# DataFlowTemplate response does not return body

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Considering the test07 stream is already created the following code snippet won't get response body in the exception stack trace.

```
    try {
        URI dataFlowUri = URI.create("http://localhost:9393");
        DataFlowOperations dataFlowOperations = new DataFlowTemplate(dataFlowUri);
        StreamDefinition streamDefinition = Stream.builder(dataFlowOperations)
                .name("test07")
                .definition("time|log")
                .create();

    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Conflict: 409 : [no body]
> at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:125)
> at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:184)
> at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
> at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:62)
> at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:418)
> at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.StreamTemplate.createStream(StreamTemplate.java:121)
> at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.dsl.StreamDefinition.(StreamDefinition.java:60)
> at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.dsl.Stream$StreamDefinitionBuilder.create(Stream.java:400)

on other hand when Post request this directly

http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions?name=test07&definition=time%20%7C%20log&description=test07

the response as follow with status code 409

> [
> {
> "logref": "DuplicateStreamDefinitionException",
> "message": "Cannot create stream test07 because another one has already been created with the same name"
> }
> ]

I want to get response body when exception occur
so anyone can help if I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I had to override the default rest template to get the response body as desired.

```
        ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

        URI dataFlowUri = URI.create("http://localhost:9393");
        DataFlowOperations dataFlowOperations = new DataFlowTemplate(dataFlowUri, restTemplate);
        StreamDefinition streamDefinition = Stream.builder(dataFlowOperations)
                .name("test07")
                .definition("time|log")
                .create();
```

thanks

Comment: I have also encountered this problem and this solution works.  much thanks.